# Apache на Mac. Не отображает PHP ошибки и выдает - HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, apache, mamp

Дано:

```
- Mac, OS X Yosemite
- MAMP (Apache/2.2.31, PHP/5.6.27)
- в php.ini (error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE и display_errors = on) 
- .htaccess файл в папке проекта отсутствует
```

Суть проблемы:

```
Не выводит php ошибки в браузере, а выдает страницу с HTTP ERROR 500.
```

В apache_error.log выводит это:

```
[Tue Jan 03 12:11:38 2017] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Jan 03 12:11:38 2017] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 21528)
[Tue Jan 03 12:11:38 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.31 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.12 
PHP/5.6.27 mod_ssl/2.2.31 OpenSSL/1.0.2j DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 
Perl/v5.24.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

В php_error.log ошибки показывает.

Как сделать так, чтобы ошибки показывались в браузере и не выдавал 500-ую страницу?

Answer (score 0):

Помогло следующее. 
Создаем **.htaccess** файл в корне сайта с таким содержанием:

> php_flag display_errors 1

Comment: еще можно в php.ini, данную строку расскоментить(или задать значение 1).